# Feedback on /review route

Tags: discussion, review

So, Jeff left a message about [the new review routes over at Chat](https://superuser.com/review/first-answers), and I took it for a spin.

Looks like the /review seems to be a subset of 2 of the 10k tools links - ie, New posts by new users & New answers by New users. The review route is lot easier/frictionless than the 10k tools to go through junk posts.

Suggestions for improvement:

- Show the regular links ( ie, edit / flag / comment ) links for those answers having less content (ex: ZOMG this works, kthxbai). On Super User there are a *lot* of such posts and having to click on show full answer and then flag is... irritating.
- @waffle's [link](https://superuser.com/review/first-answers?page=1&pagesize=50&filter=all&textfilter=thank&customsort=shortest) indicates that there is an option for "text filter" - would be nice to have (text box?) to enter this filter.
- I ran out of all my flags ( 10 Mod attention + 5 spam + 5 offensive ) in about 10 minutes, both today & yesterday ( Perhaps increment this count / ignore counts while flagging via this route / add a new mod for Super User(hint, hint))

Also:
 - I'm going to assume that this route will be at a privilege level ? 5k ? 10k ?

Comment: I totally agree with the having to click requirement being ridiculous, why make me do any more work then necessary?

Comment: Regarding running out of moderator flags, maybe on this list we should be granted the ability to see if a post already has a moderator flag already to avoid spending one unnecessarily. 10K users can already see spam and offensive flags. We wouldn't necessarily need to see the contents of the moderator flags or even how many flags there are, just as long as we can distinguish between *flagged* and *not flagged*. And I've long been in favour of increasing the total daily allocation of flags for high-arbitrary-number users so they can just plain do more flagging.

Comment: I hope Bill is enjoying all of the nice flags I've been giving him thanks to these lists.

Comment: @26years we now scale mod flags to rep, so for every 1k rep you get 1 more mod flag per day, capped at 100 per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to draw attention to this one in particular, I think that the community has a feeling about this:

> I ran out of all my flags ( 10 Mod
>   attention + 5 spam + 5 offensive ) in
>   about 10 minutes, both today &
>   yesterday ( **Perhaps increment this
>   count / ignore counts while flagging
>   via this route** / add a new mod for
>   Super User(hint, hint))

Maybe raise by x amount it per 1k of rep? Maybe lift the "ban" on this route for those with >3k (since they can vote to close too) (full disclosure: I'm 3200 rep on SO)

Putting as a CW answer

Comment: we now scale mod flags to rep, so for every 1k rep you get 1 more mod flag per day, capped at 100 per day

Comment: Thanks @JeffAtwood, I believe that's the answer.